# Using octree for cheking intersection of ray and meshes

Tags: raytracing, 3d

I wrote the code for checking intersection of ray and meshes on scene. It consist of two parts - broad phase and narrow phase.
In broad phase I build an oriented bounding box around each mesh and check intersection of ray with boxes.
In narrow phase I check intersection of ray and each triangle of the meshes from broad phase using Möller-Trumbore algorithm. In general it works well.
Now my task is to optimize broad phase using Octree. Octree as data structure is well-described and trivial enough. However, I have no idea how to apply it for raytracing and I can't find nothing about it. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Try reading "Raytracing Complex Scenes" by Kajiya.

Comment: @gallickgunner Assuming you meant Kay and Kajiya's paper, I'm not sure it suggests using Octrees, but they do cite earlier works by Glassner and Kaplan which do, e.g.  Glassner's *"Space Subdivision for Fast Ray Tracing,"* IEEE Computer Graphics
and Applications, Oct 1984

Comment: @SimonF - Yeah, Kajiya doesn't explain what an octree is but defines a whole algorithm (using a heap) how to go about using it in raytracing. And I think that's what the OP wanted, that's why.